# Merge date columns in different tables

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I am trying to merge the month column and join data from two different table. I've tried union all and full join but it didnt come out as what I expected. I want to have 1 month column, and 4 other columns (doesn't matter if they have null value) Much appreciated!

Here is the result that I want:

```
month    | new_placements | new_mrr | exits | lost_mrr
20190101 | null           | null    | 8     | 19900
20181101 | 144            | 148000  | null  | null
```

from these two tables:

```
table1

month1   | new_placements | new_mrr 
20181101 | 144            | 148000

table2

month    | exits          | lost_mrr
20190101 | 8              | 19900
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification is not at all clear.

The following query will satisfy one possible interpretation of the spec:

```
SELECT n.month1                AS month_column
     , n.new_placements        AS new_placements
     , n.new_mrr               AS new_mrr
     , ''                      AS exits
     , ''                      AS lost_mrr
  FROM table1 n
 UNION ALL
SELECT o.month                 AS month_column
     , ''                      AS new_placements
     , ''                      AS new_mrr
     , o.exits                 AS exits
     , o.lost_mrr              AS lost_mrr
  FROM table2 o
```

--

*EDIT*

With the data as shown in the question (left justified) the values appear to be strings rather than numeric values. Numeric values would be right justified. Ideally, we would have knowledge about the datatypes of the columns, preferably, the actual definitions of the two tables. We could create and populate sample tables for which the query above would not throw an error.)

With the `UNION ALL` set operator, each of the sets must have the same number of columns, and each column position needs to have the same (or compatible) datatypes.

```
SELECT n.month1                AS month_column
     , n.new_placements        AS new_placements
     , n.new_mrr               AS new_mrr
     , NULL                    AS exits
     , NULL                    AS lost_mrr
  FROM table1 n
 UNION ALL
SELECT o.month                 AS month_column
     , NULL                    AS new_placements
     , NULL                    AS new_mrr
     , o.exits                 AS exits
     , o.lost_mrr              AS lost_mrr
  FROM table2 o
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion. There are actually no null values in both table. 
I've edited the post for more clarity. I am a new sql learner so much appreciation for your help. I will try your solution.

Comment: when I tried running it states Column 2 in UNION ALL has incompatible types: INT64, STRING at [34:1]

Comment: That's why you need to describe what the actual structures are.  Why are you using "empty string" in the unions.  Just let nulls be nulls.  In addition, you only need the aliases on the first section of the union. You will also need to max the columns in an external select to flatten the structures.

Comment: @TGray: If we want to collapse rows, yes, we could can wrap the UNION ALL queries in parens, and reference that as an inline view. The outer query can use a GROUP BY clause and use aggregate functions in the SELECT list. All of that is true. But whether we "need" to do that, that depends on the actual specification.

Comment: @TGray: In the UNION ALL query, the names of the columns are determined from the first query. So, yes, the column aliases on the second query are ignored. But these can serve as documentation, and as an aid in debugging, when running just one of the queries in the UNION ALL.  Including the column aliases on the second query isn't really a problem.

Comment: @spencer7593 You are right.  I was actually referring to the second statement in the union.  Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT month_column
     , max(new_placements) as new_placements
     , max(new_mrr) as new_mrr
     , max(exits) as exits
     , max(lost_mrr) as lost_mrr
  from (SELECT n.month1                AS month_column
             , n.new_placements        AS new_placements
             , n.new_mrr               AS new_mrr
             , null                    AS exits
             , null                    AS lost_mrr
          FROM table1 n
        UNION ALL
        SELECT o.month 
             , null 
             , null
             , o.exits
             , o.lost_mrr
          FROM table2 o) as a
GROUP BY month_column;
```